# How can I import two css frameworks dynamically in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, import

I am working in a project with react and my client wants me to have a button to toogle between Bootstrap and Foundation.

I have checked some options and I came to the conclusion that it is best to use hooks to manage each of the state, but I don't know how to import them correctly.

```
const theme = (mode: string) =>
  mode === "dark"
    ? "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
    : "foundation-sites/dist/css/foundation.min.css";

export default theme;



import theme from "./theme/experiment.js";

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

I expect React to import the correct theme base on the value of "mode"

Answer (score 0):

You can import css in your virtual DOM in react component.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
```

That means you can change href attr by using state.

```
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  type="text/css" 
  href={this.props.isBootstrap ? "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" : "foundation-sites/dist/css/foundation.min.css"} 
/>
```

Of course you can change your css by state or props.